# how the parameters are passed into io.py in mxnet

Tags: python

In mxnet code ,there is some code in io.py,where the kwargs are passed from?I can't find any function call creator.

```
def _make_io_iterator(handle):
    """Create an io iterator by handle."""
    def creator(*args, **kwargs):
       param_keys = []
       param_vals = []

       for k, val in kwargs.items():

  creator.__name__ = iter_name
  creator.__doc__ = doc_str
  return creator
```

Comment: `_make_io_iterator` returns a function, locally called `creator`. That function can take arbitrary `*args, **kwargs`, which will be passed in whenever that function eventually gets called. Without seeing more about how this is used, it's hard to say when that would be. Here is one use of the outer `_make_io_iterator` function, within the same module: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/io.py#L601. Could you clarify what you'd like to know?

Comment: i'd like to know when creator function are called .From top file,there is mx.io.CSVIter（data_csv=,data_shape=,）.I don't know how it passed to creator.By the way,where does __name__ and __doc__ come from in creator

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still not clear to me. `creator` is just the local name, with `_make_io_iterator`, the resulting function can be assigned to any name once it's returned. Read up on *"decorators"*, and note that functions are first class objects in Python. `__name__` and `__doc__` are being assigned, why do you think they *"come from"* anywhere? They are the names used by Python, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html for the standard attributes.

Comment: Ok,i get it now.But i still was confused how the CSVIter params passed to creator(**kwargs).Maybe i need look into code.

Comment: Looks like the question is about basic Python syntax and is not related to the MXNet tag. I would advise to remove tag MXNet.